# Decomposing a string into words separared by spaces, ignoring spaces within quoted strings, and considering ( and ) as words

Tags: php, regex, matching

How can I explode the following string:

```
+test +word any -sample (+toto +titi "generic test") -column:"test this" (+data id:1234)
```

into

```
Array('+test', '+word', 'any', '-sample', '(', '+toto', '+titi', '"generic test"', ')', '-column:"test this"', '(', '+data', 'id:1234', ')')
```

I would like to extend the boolean fulltext search SQL query, adding the feature to specify specific columns using the notation `column:value` or `column:"valueA value B"`.

How can I do this using `preg_match_all($regexp, $query, $result)`, i.e., what is the correct regular expression to use?

Or more generally, what would be the most appropriate regular expression to decompose a string into words not containing spaces, where spaces within text between quotes is not considered spaces, for the sake of defining a word, and `(` and `)` are considered words, independent of being surrounded by spaces. For example `xxx"yyy zzz"` should be considered a single world. And `(aaa)` should be three words `(`, `aaa` and `)`.

I have tried something like `/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|\S+/`, but with limited/no success.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is it necessary to do this with regexes? Also, how about edge cases such as `"one""two"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think PCRE verbs can be used to achieve your goal:

```
preg_split('/".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\(|\))| /', '+test +word any -sampe (+toto +titi "generic test") -column:"test this" (+data id:1234)',-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

https://3v4l.org/QnpB9
https://regex101.com/r/pw1mEd/1
https://3v4l.org/dNMkf (with test data)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the various parts using alternations:

```
(?:[^\s()":]*:)?"[^"]+"|[^\s()]+|[()]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `[^\s()":]*:` Match optional non whitespace chars other than `(` `)` `"`  `:` and then match `:`
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `"[^"]+"` Match from an opening double quote till closing double quote
- `|` Or
- `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars other than `(` or `)`
- `|` Or
- `[()]` Match either `(` or `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqL9W3/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5n0GB)

Example code

```
$re = '/(?:[^\s()":]*:)?"[^"]+"|[^\s()]+|[()]/';
$str = '+test +word any -sampe (+toto +titi "generic test") -column:"test this" (+data id:1234)';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => +test
    [1] => +word
    [2] => any
    [3] => -sampe
    [4] => (
    [5] => +toto
    [6] => +titi
    [7] => "generic test"
    [8] => )
    [9] => -column:"test this"
    [10] => (
    [11] => +data
    [12] => id:1234
    [13] => )
)
```

Comment: @mickmackusa Nope, it is from copying generated code from regex101.